# Left join with some field from the same source field and table but different condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have tables that look like this:

```
ProductList
+------+----------------+--------------+----------+--------+-------+
|  id  | product_number | product_type | location | status | price |
+------+----------------+--------------+----------+--------+-------+
|  1   | A-01           | A001         | Nevada   | READY  | 5000  |
|  2   | B-02           | A002         | Texas    | STORED | 6000  |
|  3   | A-01           | A002         | Utah     | READY  | 6000  |
|  4   | A-02           | B003         | Utah     | READY  | 8000  |
|  5   | B-01           | A001         | Nevada   | STORED | 5000  |
+------+----------------+--------------+----------+--------+-------+
```

`id` is the primary key.

```
Supervisor
+------+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------+
|  id  | month | product_type | location | unit_sold | income |
+------+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------+
|  1   | 1     | A001         | Nevada   | 5         | 25000  |
|  2   | 3     | A002         | Texas    | 6         | 36000  |
|  3   | 1     | A002         | Utah     | NULL      | NULL   |
|  4   | 4     | B003         | Utah     | 4         | 32000  |
|  5   | 2     | A001         | Nevada   | 6         | 30000  |
+------+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

I was asked that the result should be like this table (this is actually my estimation) :

```
SalesTarget table

Location : Nevada

+------+----------------+--------+--------+---------------+---------------+
|      |     STATUS     |      TOTAL      |   1st MONTH   |   2nd MONTH   |
| TYPE | READY | STORED |  UNIT  | PRICE  | UNIT | INCOME | UNIT | INCOME |
+------+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
| A001 |   6   |    8   |  14    |  70000 |  5   | 25000  |  6   | 30000  |
| A002 |   7   |    4   |  11    |  66000 |  3   | 39000  |  0   |   0    |
| B001 |   3   |    6   |  19    |  95000 |  0   |   0    |  0   |   0    |
| B002 |   5   |    5   |  10    | 100000 |  4   | 40000  |  6   | 60000  |
+------+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
```

The table only shows data only from specific `location`. `STATUS READY`  is a cumulative from unit that has the same type and location which has **READY** state and so for `STATUS STORED`. `TOTAL` is total unit / price of the same type in that `Location`.

Unit and income in `SalesTarget` table can be NULL and it will be entered by the user, but they are classified by `Supervisor.month` (and also, it's for 12th month).
I join both table (ProductList and Supervisor) by `product_type`.

I tried using prepared statement query command like this, but it didn't give my exact result that I want.

```
SELECT

pl.product_type AS TYPE,
SUM(IF(pl.status = ? , 1, 0)) AS READY,
SUM(IF(pl.status = ? , 1, 0)) AS STORED,
SUM((IF((pl.status = ? OR pl.status = ? ), 1, 0))) AS UNIT_TOTAL,
SUM((IF((pl.status = ? OR pl.status = ? ), pl.price, 0))) AS PRICE_TOTAL,
IF(sv.month=1, sv.unit_sold, 0) AS UNIT1,
IF(sv.month=1, sv.income, 0) AS INCOME1,
IF(sv.month=2, sv.unit_sold, 0) AS UNIT2,
IF(sv.month=2, sv.income, 0) AS INCOME2

FROM ProductList pl
LEFT OUTER JOIN Supervisor sv ON pl.product_type = sv.product_type
WHERE pl.location = ?
GROUP BY pl.product_type
ORDER BY TYPE DESC
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why is the total for `A001` 14 in the expected output? It looks like it should be just 11?

Comment: `A001` = 14 because it's actually cumulative of all `product_type` from the same location regardless of status in `ProductList` table.<br/>
Actually it's just estimation.

Comment: Is it the total of `unit_sold`? 5 + 6 = 11, not 14.

Comment: +1 for cleanely formatted and well drafted question. :) Suggest you to use `case when` instead of `if` and interms of `pivot` look, `Group_Concat()` could be useful.

Comment: As Barmar and others question here, your Total Unit seems to be wrong in the expected output. `A002 = 6, A001 = 11, B003 = 4` and there's none for B002 as it's not in the table...Is that right? Please clarify and update your data.

Comment: Sorry if it's really confusing. It is said that `unit_sold` at `id=1` is actually will be placed in **1ST MONTH UNIT** and it's as in the `UNIT1` in SQL syntax. It's based on user input manually inside `SalesTarget` table.

About the tables, it's actually a few sample from the actual huge ammount of data.

Comment: When you give us sample data and expected output, we need them to match. That way, we can see the relationship between the input and output, and perform tests to ensure that we get the expected result.